# Using typedef and struct to create bitfield

Tags: c, structure, bit-fields

Hey all this is for C programming.

Here are the questions as they were presented to me, can someone tell me how I would correctly write code for the following statements in C? FYI i already answered this quiz but my professor won't post the answers himself. I did very poorly when he graded it, but **to help make sense of this i will provide my answers (as incorrect as they are)**

1: Create a structure that will hold bits the represent the following:

- count: a 4 bit BCD number
- red LED: 1 bit
- green LED: 1 bit
- motor direction: 2 bits

Name the structure motorStatus

Use typedef to name this new data type: mtrStatus_t

```
typedef unsigned char mtrStatus_t;

struct motorStatus mtrStatus_t {
    mtrStatus_t count: 4;
    mtrStatus_t redLED: 1;
    mtrStatus_t greenLED: 1;
    mtrStatus_t motorDirection: 2;
};
```

2: Create a new instance of the structure and name it motor1Status

```
motorStatus = motor1Status;
```

3: Write statements to initialize the new structure members as follows:

- count: 9 BCD
- red LED: 1
- green LED: 0
- Motor Direction: 10

  count: 0x09;
  redLED: 0x01;
  greenLED: 0x00
  motorDirection: 0x0A

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first one I would do something like this:

```
typedef struct motorStatus  
{
    int count: 4;
    int redLED: 1;
    int greenLED: 1;
    int motorDirection: 2;
} mtrStatus_t;
```

The second one is more like:

```
mtrStatus_t motor1status;
```

and finally:

```
motor1status.count = 0x9;
motor1status.redLED = 1;
motor1status.greenLED = 0;
motor1status.motorDirection = 0x02;
```

Count is a hex number because it is BCD (Binary coded decimal) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary-coded_decimal
In BCD, you use 4 bits to represent the numbers 0-9, there are some unused bit patterns, so the easy way to work with it is to just use hex (which also uses 4 bits to represent the numbers 0x0-0xf), but in BCD you just don't use the numbers 0xa-0xf.

The reason motorDirection is 0x02 is because he wants motor direction of 10, but it is a 2 bit field, so I am assuming that he means 10 binary, which is 0x02 hex.

Comment: Hey Chris how does that work............I see how you put it together but I don't get what the point of a typedef is..

Comment: motorStatus is the name of the struct, but mtrStatus_t is the name of the typedef of that struct... See this question for more details on this archaic syntax: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/612328/difference-between-struct-and-typedef-struct-in-c

Comment: hey Chris everything looks great and thanks for the explanation on motorDirection as a 2 bit. One more thing...why is count written as hex in initialization of structure members?

Comment: Updated post with small blurb about BCD

Answer (score 0):

Consider meeting these requirements in the order they are specified. Note that some requirements are merged together as one. This is often the case for assignments; Lecturers aren't always perfect linguists or logicians, particularly IT lecturers.

```
1: Create a structure that will hold bits the represent the following:

count: a 4 bit BCD number
red LED: 1 bit
green LED: 1 bit
motor direction: 2 bits

Name the structure motorStatus
```

Respond to this, first, without using typedef. Use the type `int` for bitfields. Next requirement:

```
Use typedef to name this new data type: mtrStatus_t
```

You've demonstrated the ability to write basic typedefs. `typedef unsigned char mtrStatus_t;` means "I define mtrStatus_t to alias unsigned char". Now, write a basic typedef like this that means "I define mtrStatus_t to alias struct motorStatus". Put it after the `struct motorStatus` definition, so that the compiler can see what it's aliasing.

```
2: Create a new instance of the structure and name it motor1Status
```

To clarify, your lecturer is asking you to declare a variable named `motor1Status`, which has the type `mtrStatus_t` or `struct motorStatus`. I presume you can declare variables, but correct me if I'm wrong.

```
3: Write statements to initialize the new structure members as follows:

count: 9 BCD
red LED: 1
green LED: 0
Motor Direction: 10

count: 0x09; redLED: 0x01; greenLED: 0x00 motorDirection: 0x0A
```

Your lecturer is asking for initialisation, *not assignment*. In `char str[] = "fubar";` and `char str[] = {'h','e','l','l','o','\0'};`, str is declared and initialised to store a string corresponding to "fubar". In `char str[6]; strcpy(str, "fubar");` str is declared without an initialisation, and each byte in "fubar" is copied (assigned) to the corresponding positions in str. How do you initialise a struct? Very similarly to the second *str* initialisation.

```
struct length_prefixed_string {
    size_t length;
    int zero;
    char string[];
};

/* Initialisation here: */
struct length_prefixed_string hello = { .length = 5,
                                        .string = "hello" };
```

This example uses a flexible array member, which can only be declared at the end of a struct: `char string[];`. It conveys an array of unknown length located at the end of the struct, which isn't counted towards `sizeof (struct length_prefix_string)`. For this reason, the example stores the *unknown length* in the *length* argument. This is a little off-topic, but you *can see an initialisation* (as opposed to an assignment) above. This example differentiates initialisation from assignment; You can't assign the `.string` member of this struct with `hello.string = "hello";`.

Another difference is: Any members not mentioned by the initialisation will be assigned a *zero* value (but *only* when an initialisation is present), hence the value of `hello.zero` in the above example will be 0. For this reason, you can declare an array and zero-fill it with one statement: `int array[size] = { 0 };` (another difference between assignment and initialisation: `int array[size]; array = { 0 };` is invalid). Having said that, it'd be a good idea to ignore this fact for the purpose of your task, and explicitly initialise greenLED so that your marking examiner can't misunderstand.

I do hope I was helpful, here...

Comment: You're a wizard modifiable lvalue, thank you so much for your post. I do have a lot of questions but I'm going to do a little bit of research on my own to see if I can hash them out...if not....you can be sure you'll be hearing from me soon :) Thanks again!